# WCS Seach(SOLR) filter query to include or exclude given catalog_id categories

Tags: solr, wcs

We are trying to limit WebSphere Commerce Search/SOLR keyword search to current catalog categories only by using fq=catalog_id:"1000002" and other fq values but still getting data from categories that are not part of catalog_id 1000002. Are there any other approaches to include current catalog categories only during keyword search?

We are on WCS8. I tried commenting <_config:field name="categoryname"/> in wc-search.xml and it didn't work either though it's not ideal scenario since we still would like the searches to work against current customer/site catalog_id.

Comment: If you can, try passing "debugQuery=true" in your request to Solr and see if Solr is parsing your query as expected. Look for the "parsedquery" output under the "debug" node.

Comment: @HectorCorrea I see many SOLR calls made for keyword search alone, will modify the code to send debug for keyword search profile alone to see what it's doing. What am I supposed to check in the response data since I do see catalog_id value in one of fq fields? I will test SOLR query as well and see if it gives expected results.

Comment: With `debugQuery=true` you will see two properties (`parsedQuery` and `parsed_filter_queries`) in the results under the `debug` node of the output. Make sure the `parsed_filter_queries` has the values that you expect.

Comment: I see following under parsed_filter_queries when I queries SOLR directly. I believe SOLR queries are working fine.

`<arr name="parsed_filter_queries">
<str>
-(+catenttype_id_ntk_cs:ItemBean +parentCatentry_id:[* TO *])
</str>
<str>catalog_id:1000002</str>
<str>storeent_id:143051</str>
<str>published:1</str>
<str>price_USD_1033377:[* TO *]</str>
</arr>`

Comment: I think the tricky part is with the items not being relevant to current keyword search since same items are in current catalog_id and a different catalog but in category whose name has 'candy' word in it in the other catalog. What kind of fq we can use to limit the keyword search for categories under current catalog only?

Comment: We have following data for parentCatgroup_id_search field in SOLR index, I tried `fq=parentCatgroup_id_search:1000002_*` and it seem to be working fine so far.

`<lst name="parentCatgroup_id_search">
 <int name="1000002_30744573438">32</int>
 <int name="1000002_307445334468">220</int>
</lst>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with fq field or value since it's working as expected. Issue was with categoryname qf, so had to customize this part to include dynamic categoryname_ qf and the search returns correct results now.